# Subtracting Direction cosine matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, quaternions

Say I have a rotation matrix $C(q) \in R^{3\times3}$ which is a function of a Hamilton quaternion $q=[q_w, q_x, q_y, q_z]^T=[q_w, q_v]^T$ where $q_v$ is the vector part of the quaternion.
The Direction cosine matrix is defined as
$$R=(q_w^2-q_v^Tq_v)I+2q_v^Tq_v+2q_w[q_v]_\times$$

where $[q_v]_\times$ is the skew symmetric matrix.

Is it correct to write:
$$\left[C(q)-C(\hat{q})\right]p=C(q-\hat{q})p$$

where $p \in R^3$

Is this correct in the case of a small difference between $q$ and $\hat{q}$?

Comment: "Direction cosine" matrix has an "early 20th century" flavor, but not very used nowadays. You should simply say that it is a rotation matrix (property $CC^T=I$ (or $C^{-1}=C^T$)  with $det(C)=1$).

Comment: I edited my question to reflect your suggestion.